# for loop only returning the last word in a list of many words

Tags: python

```
for word in wordStr:
    word = word.strip()
print word
```

When the above code analyzes a .txt with thousands of words, why does it only return the last word in the .txt file? What do I need to do to get it to return all the words in the text file?

Comment: That doesn't return anything; it prints something. You return things with `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because the variable word is the current word, when finish the file, is the last one:

```
def stuff():
    words = []
    for word in wordStr:
        words.append(word.strip())
    print words
    return words
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're overwriting `word` in the loop, not really a good idea. You can try something like:

```
wordlist = ""
for word in wordStr:
    wordlist = "%s %s"%(wordlist,word.strip())
print wordlist[1:]
```

This is fairly primitive Python and I'm sure there's a more Pythonic way to do it with list comprehensions and all that new-fangled stuff :-) but I usually prefer readability where possible.

What this does is to maintain a list of the words in a separate string and then add each stripped word to the end of that list. The `[1:]` at the end is simply to get rid of the initial space that was added when the first word was tacked on to the end of the empty word list.

It will suffer eventually as the word count becomes substantial since tacking things on to the end of a string is less optimal than other data structures. However, even up to 10,000 words (with the print removed), it's still *well* under a second of execution time.

At 50,000 words it becomes noticeable, taking 3 seconds on my box. If you're going to be processing that sort of quantity, you would probably opt for a real list-based solution like (equivalent to above but with a different underlying data structure):

```
wordlist = []
for word in wordStr:
    wordlist.append (word.strip())
print wordlist
```

That takes about 0.22 seconds (without the print) to do my entire dictionary file, some 110,000 words.

Comment: This isn't maintaining a list... you're repeatedly building new strings containing all the words seen so far separated by spaces. Building each string is O(n), so overall you're O(n^2). This is a very inefficient way to do a very simple task; to my eye it's also much more complicated and less readable than straightforward approaches using "new-fangled stuff" like list comprehensions.

Comment: That's you opinion, @Ben, and you're entitled to it. That's why I said "something like" and also mentioned the other stuff. Nothing in the question indicated that a list was desired, only that they wanted the words returned. As for performance, the question was for thousands of words and it does 10K in about 0.32 seconds. Once you get up to 50K, it becomes noticable at about 3 seconds, but it would depend on the word count.

Comment: No, but you state that you're maintaining a list, which is not strictly what your code is doing. While fine informally, that's probably not a great thing to tell someone who obviously is still a beginner Pythoner (if not a beginner programmer). And I'm genuinely surprised that someone would find this more readable than the obvious for loop or list comprehension, but yes, readability is certainly not an objective subject.

Comment: Aah, I see now where the 'list' came from, my misunderstanding. I didn't actually mean list in the formal Python sense, just a list of words (in a list, or an array or a tree or, in this case, a string). I'll clarify.

Answer (score 1):

To print all the words in `wordStr` (assuming that `wordStr` is some kind of iterable that returning strings), you can simply write

```
for word in wordStr:
    word = word.strip()
    print word # Notice that the only difference is the indentation on this line
```

Python cares about indentation, so in your code the print statement is outside the loop and is only executed once.  In the modified version, the print statement is inside the loop and is executed once per word.

Comment: @user1294377: Actually, if all you want to do is print, this is probably a better solution than mine. It doesn't use up lots of storage space for the list.

Answer (score 0):

[List comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) should make your code snazzier and more pythonic.

```
wordStr = 'here are some words'
print [word.strip() for word in wordStr.split()]
```

returns

```
['here', 'are', 'some', 'words']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know why the code in your example is "returning" only the last word (actually it's not returning anything, it's printing a single word), then I'm afraid nothing here is going to help you very much.

I know that sounds hostile, but I don't wish to be. It seems from your question that you are throwing bits of Python together with little real understanding of the fundamental basics of programming in Python.

Now don't get me wrong, trying stuff out is a great early learning activity, and having a task to motivate your learning is also a great way to do it. So I don't want to tell you to stop! But whether you're trying to learn to program *or* just have a task that needs you to write a program, you aren't going to get very far without developing an understanding of the **fundamental** underlying issues that make your example not do what you want it to do.

We can tell you here that this:

```
for word in wordStr:
    word = word.strip()
print word
```

is a program that roughly means "for every `word` in `wordStr`, bind `word` to the result of `word.strip()`; then after all that, print the contents of `word`", whereas what you wanted is likely:

```
for word in wordStr:
    word = word.strip()
    print word
```

which is a program that roughly means "for every `word` in `wordStr`, bind `word` to the result of `word.strip()` and then print `word`". And that solves your immediate problem. But you're going to run into many more problems of a very similar nature, and without an understanding of the very basics you won't be able to see that they're all "of a kind", and you'll just end up asking more questions here.

What you need is to gain a basic understanding of how variables, statements, loops, etc work in Python. You will probably *eventually* gain that if you just keep trying to apply code and ask questions here. But Stack Overflow is not the most efficient resource for gaining that understanding; a much better bet would be to find yourself a good book or tutorial (there's an official one at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Here endeth the soap box.