# Python For Loops Returning Last Value | Explanation

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a simple problem which I've solved but it would be great if someone could explain **why** for loops do this in python and if there is a more elegant way. Really sorry if this is a dumb question - I have done my best to try multiple methods and look at related questions, but I still unsure why it doesn't work.

I've read this post, but it doesn't quite explain my issue: [for loop only returning the last word in a list of many words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882209/for-loop-only-returning-the-last-word-in-a-list-of-many-words)

If I **print** x, it returns every month name perfectly.

```
monthName = []

for i in df["Month_Number"]:
    x = calendar.month_abbr[i]
    print(x)
```

The below stores the result (month names) it in a nice clean list (which is great).

```
monthName = []

for i in df["Month_Number"]:
    x = calendar.month_abbr[i]
    monthName.append(x)
```

I would then go on to solve my problem by doing this:

```
df["Month_Name"] = monthName
```

> Why does the following ONLY return **"NONE"** when i integrate into the loop?

```
monthName = []

for i in df["Month_Number"]:
    x = calendar.month_abbr[i]
    df["Month_Name"] = monthName.append(x)
```

> Why does the following only return the **last value**:

```
for i in df["Month_Number"]:
    df["Month_Name"] = calendar.month_abbr[i]
```

I understand (to some degree) as to why append returns none, but was more interested in understanding why other approaches only return the LAST value.

Comment: Because `monthname.append()` returns `None`, not the appended list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does append return none in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-return-none-in-this-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First way, `append()` doesn't return anything, so its return value will be `None`.

Second way, nothing is "being returned", you are overwriting the value within a loop, then only inspecting the value of the **entire `df["Month_Name"]` column** after the final iteration, which by definition, will be the last value.

I think using loops is the wrong approach here, you should be using `apply` or `map` functions instead, but if you wanted a loop, I might suggest this

```
df["Month_Name"] = [calendar.month_abbr[i] for i in df["Month_Number"]]
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for indulging this - I appreciate it. Your suggestion worked so thank you. How is this different to my approach? They look the same except you've done it in a one-line list comprehension. I was going to create a dictionary of Month Numbers : Month Names and then map it back, but I wanted to test other ways.

Comment: The `append()`, then `=` approach and the list-comprehension are the same. Just less code and no temporary list variable lying around