# only get the last result of the xml file

Tags: python, xml

here is my code, I try to use the print function to check and I tag what I have found next to the code using#

```
def file(entry):
    file_name = str(entry)
    if file_name.endswith('.xml'):

        tree = ET.parse(file_name)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for i in range(len(root)):
            in_text = str(root[i][5].text).lower()
```

print(in_text)# here I still get all data

```
    elif file_name.endswith('.json'):
        with open(file_name) as f:
            j_text = json.load(f)
            in_text = (j_text['text']).lower()
            
            
        
    else:
        root_error = tk.Tk()
        root_error.title('Error !')
        canvas_error = tk.Canvas(root_error, height=10, width=100 )
        canvas_error.pack()
        label_error = tk.Label(root_error, text= 'file type dont support')
        label_error.pack()
        root_error.mainloop()


    remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits)
    res = in_text.translate(remove_digits)
```

print(res)# here I get only the last one

```
    token_text = sent_tokenize(res)
        
    sent_string = ('\n'.join(token_text))
        
    removed_pun = str(sent_string).translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
        
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    tokens = word_tokenize(str(removed_pun))
    result = [i for i in tokens if not i in stop_words]
        
    porter = PorterStemmer()
    stemmed = [porter.stem(word) for word in result]
        
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    final_text = ' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in stemmed])
        
        
    lower_label_out['text'] = final_text
```

but when I use the code only like this

```
tree = ET.parse('books.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


for i in range(len(root)):
    print(root[i][5].text)
```

I get all the data, I don't know why I only get the last data, how can I fix it

Comment: in your `for` loop you overwrite `out_text` in every loop run. You could use a list and append to that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [for loop only returning the last word in a list of many words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882209/for-loop-only-returning-the-last-word-in-a-list-of-many-words)

Comment: not really cause I have already tried that method, I put the label_out  inside the loop still only get the last data

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comment, your problem is that you overwrite the `label['text']` value in each iteration. With the new indentation, you just shifted the problem from the `out_text` variable to the `label['text']` variable. If you want to get a list of all `out_text`s, I'd suggest you to do the following.

```
out_text = []
for i in range(len(root)):
    # in each iteration, append the new string to the list
    out_text.append(str(root[i][0].text)

label_out['text'] = out_text
```

In each iteration, the value of `str(root[i][0].text)` is appended to the list, and finally assigned to the `label_out['text']` value.
However, I'd suggest you to look into how `for` loops work in python, as you could write the same statement as follows:

```
out_text = []
for ro in root:
    out_text.append(str(ro[0]).text)

label_out['text'] = out_text
```

The reason why the `print()` statement works is that you put it into the for loop, so each time the code passes there, the current value is printed to the screen.

Comment: thank you very much. I understand what I have done wrong now, but now I do a lot of preprocessing on the out_text before it put into the label, I still get the same problem. I change you code a little to something like this.

Comment: out_text = []
    for word in final_text:
        out_text.append(str(word[0]))

    lower_label_out['text'] = final_text

Comment: I still get only the last data, and I have checked that final_text still got all data

Comment: could you please edit your question to include this? Then I could take a look at it. In a comment, it is just one single line which is hard to decipher (especially with indentation). Also, could you add the output from the `print(final_text)` and perhaps also `print(type(final_text))` in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The last line in your `for` lop is mis-indented, so it only prints the last element.

Try changing it to:

```
for i in range(len(root)):
        out_text = str(root[i][0].text)
        label_out['text'] = out_text #note the new indentation
```

and see if it works.

Comment: still, only get the last element.

Comment: in fact, when I use the print function to print (out_text) it still shows all data, but when I use label_out['text'] it only shows the last data

Comment: @lessthanenough Then you'll have to post much more of your code, for example - to see how label_out is structured.

Comment: that all the code... I put a     print(out_text) in front of label_out still I get all data but with     label_out I get only the last data.

Comment: @lessthanenough That can't be all the code. Where's the `label_out = xxx` line?

Comment: I forget about that one, sorry. here is it :     label_out = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='white', wraplength=500)
label_out.place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relwidth=1, relheight=0.95)